# Network connectivity between Amazon EC2 instances and Amazon S3

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

What is the network bandwidth between Amazon ec2 instances and Amazon S3?  I am trying to figure out how long it would take me to copy data from Amazon S3 to Amazon EC2 (and vice versa)

Answer (score 0):

This isn't published information, but ... it's fast.

On smaller instance classes, total Ethernet bandwidth available to the instance can easily be consumed by requests to S3, implying that the limitation isn't the connection to S3.

Provisioning a VPC endpoint for S3 access *might* also improve throughput to S3.

Bottom line, benchmark it.  You will, of course, want to use a bucket that's provisioned in the same region as the instance, for both cost and performance reasons.  Data transfer between EC2 and S3 is not billed within a region.

Comment: Thanks. How does performance between EC2 and S3 compare to performance between 2 EC2 instances?  Comparable, faster, slower?

Comment: It depends on the network connectivity provided by the instance class.  A t2.micro and an hi1.4xlarge, communicating with each other, would be limited by the bandwidth allowed for the t2.micro, which itself should be able to communicate with S3 at a comparable speed, while the hi1.4xlarge would have a faster S3 connection because it has a faster Ethernet connection.  But it's hard to be extremely specific on this.